# Assertion desc failed at src/libswscale/swscale_internal.h:668

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I ran to the very strange problem. I'm using `FFMPEG` `gdigrab` device to capture the desktop. Here's what I do

```
...
        options = NULL;
        av_dict_set(&options, "framerate", "30", NULL);
        av_dict_set(&options, "offset_x", QString::number(geometry.x() + 10).toLatin1().data(), NULL);
        av_dict_set(&options, "offset_y", QString::number(geometry.y() + 10).toLatin1().data(), NULL);
        av_dict_set(&options, "video_size", QString(QString::number(geometry.width() - 20) + "x" + QString::number(geometry.height() - 20)).toLatin1().data(), NULL);
        av_dict_set(&options, "show_region", "1", NULL);

        AVInputFormat* inputFormat = av_find_input_format("gdigrab");
        avformat_open_input(&inputFormatContext, "desktop", inputFormat, &options);
...
        AVPacket* packet = (AVPacket*)av_malloc(sizeof(AVPacket));
        av_init_packet(packet);

        AVFrame* frame = av_frame_alloc();
        AVFrame* outFrame = av_frame_alloc();

        int nbytes = av_image_get_buffer_size(outCodecContext->pix_fmt,
                                          outCodecContext->width,
                                          outCodecContext->height,
                                          32);

        uint8_t* outBuffer = (uint8_t*)av_malloc(nbytes);

        avpicture_fill((AVPicture*)outFrame, outBuffer,
                   AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P,
                   outCodecContext->width, outCodecContext->height);

        SwsContext* swsContext = sws_getContext(inputCodecContext->width,
                                            inputCodecContext->height,
                                            inputCodecContext->pix_fmt,
                                            outCodecContext->width,
                                            outCodecContext->height,
                                            outCodecContext->pix_fmt,
                                            SWS_BICUBIC, NULL, NULL, NULL);
...
```

And as far as I can tell, application crashing right after `sws_getContext(...`

It crashes with windows error message

```
this application has requested the runtime to terminate it in an unusual way
```

So I can't even debug where the problem was.

There's also a message in the console

```
Assertion desc failed at src/libswscale/swscale_internal.h:668
```

The strange thing is - I don't even have any `swscale_internal.h` file

Please tell me if I need to provide additional information to get help.

Comment: Run your executable under a debugger and `break` on `abort`.  In `gdb` that would simply be `b abort`.  Then have a look at the call stack.

Comment: Can't find where I can set that flag for `CDB`. Can I do it somehow?

Comment: Try [`bm abort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bp--bu--bm--set-breakpoint-)

Answer (score 0):

In recent version of `FFmpeg` that assertion tells that `outCodecContext->pix_fmt` is not correctly set. And also `avpicture_fill` is deprecated, use `av_image_fill_arrays` instead. If you use old version of FFmpeg you may ignore deprecation. But I recommend using latest FFmpeg. Hope that helps.